# Using of regex in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use regex in my python script but didn't work.

I have a python script that will suppose to get these data in a txt file and transfer to csv file:

Example data in the txt file

```
  0.0 testing_1
  1.0 testing_2
 -5.0 testing_3
  4.5 testing_4
```

I want to use regex for the first 4 characters of the line which contains a space, another space or a dash, number, then a dot. Example regex: ( |-)\d. I want to use regex since the characters are changing but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
import re

# open and read the txt file.
text_file = open("extractspamreport.txt", "r")

# Read each line of text file and save it in lines. 
lines = text_file.readlines()

# Make a csv file.
mycsv = csv.writer(open('OutPut.csv', 'w'))

# Write header for csv file.
mycsv.writerow(['Rule Name'])
mycsv.writerow(['Points'])

#problem starts here
testvar = re.search(" ( |-)\d+.", lines)

n = 0
for line in lines: 
    n = n + 1
n = 0
for line in lines: 
    n = n + 1
    if testvar in line:
        #this is just for checking if the regex is correct
        print("hello world")
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test2.py", line 24, in <module>

  testvar = re.search(" ( |-)\d+.", lines)

  File "C:\Users\testf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\re.py", line 173, in search

  return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Is there any way to get that data using regex?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `lines` is a list, but argument to `re.search` is expecting a string.

Comment: you are passing array instead of string in this line testvar = re.search(" ( |-)\d+.", lines) move this line inside loop and pass it "line"

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. first of all the problem is you are not passing the correct type of param to `re.search()`

readlines() return a list not a string so..

lines == list

***READLINES***

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm

***JOIN***

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/

so lets fix it.
use Join to pass a list to string

lets use `re.findall()` to get all matches

u can copy and paste this code for test it works

[Repl.it - Online Python Editor and IDE](https://repl.it/repls/LinearCriticalControlflowgraph) <-with the code already

if u wanna reprocude the error just change the "string" to "lines" in the `re.findall()`

```
import re

lines = ["-5.0 testing_3"," 1.0 testing_2"," 0.0 testing_2"]
separator = "," #or any other separator u want to the string u can use espace too
string = separator.join(lines)
 #join() is used here to transform a list in a string     
result = re.findall("( \d+|-\d+).",string)
print(result) 
 #the group is the string matched by () on regex and if u
 #create more ()"groups" u can use group(1) and so on

'''
#the result 
>>>['-5', ' 1', ' 0']

'''
```

and if u want use variables on strings its easy like this

```
"{}{}{}".format(var1,var2,var3) #each {} is one var
```